# I am getting version issues in android Gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting following error when I try to build my app:

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
> Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

**Build.gradle (project)**

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.4.0'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.3"
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

**Build.gradle(app)**

```
android {
    namespace 'com.sturec.sturecadmin'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sturec.sturecadmin"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select Gradle from the settings and select the relevant version.

[image: Gradle settings jdk]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it in the code, go to Build.gradle(app) and change the line

```
    kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

to the version you are actually targetting (17 by the error message you posted)